# how to show post tags in my template system

Tags: php

i should say i'm not english so sorry for word problems!
i want to show post tags in my template system, this work perfect alone:

```
     <?php
$text= "hi,ok,bye";
    $numKeys=substr_count($text, ',');
    for($i=0;$i<=$numKeys;$i++){
        $exp=explode(",",$text);
        $tags=$exp[$i];
        echo "<a href='http://test.com/$tags'><strong>$tags</strong></a> ";
    }
?>
```

but when i use it in my template system it doesn't work (post title,time,... work perfect just post tags don't work!( just show the first tag! just one tag like : hi ) ):

```
     //posts
$start = strpos($theme, '<start>');
$end = strpos($theme, '</end>', $start + strlen('</end>'));
$posty = substr($theme, $start, $end - $start);
$post = $posty;
$post = str_replace('<start>','',$post);
$post = str_replace('</end>','',$post);
$post_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `bid`='{$bid}' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$posts = '';
if($post_query) {
    while($post_data = mysql_fetch_array($post_query)) {
        $postid = $post_data['id'];
        $post_temp = $post;
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_title]', $post_data['title'], $post_temp);
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_content]', $post_data['content'], $post_temp);
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_date]',$post_data['date'], $post_temp);
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_author]',$post_data['author'],$post_temp);
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_comments]',$post_data['comments'],$post_temp);
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_full_content]','',$post_temp);


$text= "hi,ok,bye";
    $numKeys=substr_count($text, ',');
    for($i=0;$i<=$numKeys;$i++){
        $exp=explode(",",$text);
        $tags=$exp[$i];
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_tag]',$tags,$post_temp);
    }


        $posts .= $post_temp;
    }
}
$theme = str_replace($post, $posts, $theme);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesnt work? Does it give you an error? Doesn't it display properly?

Comment: i mean it just show the first tag! just one tag like : hi

Answer (score 0):

[`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) says

> str_replace — Replace *all* occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

This means, all `[post_tag]`s will be replaced with the first `$tags` value. Every following `$tags` will have no effect.